# React Native Webview Add Parameters to Local URI

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am using a local SPA with react native `webview` and I am trying to send a parameter to it so it can load with that parameter.

I have added the source as the following

```
let source = (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file:///android_asset/' : '') + 'SPA/index.html';
```

This is handling android and iOS but whenever I add ? with a parameter I get URI not found on this server for example if I add

```
let source = (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file:///android_asset/' : '') + 'SPA/index.html?parameter=foo';
```

or if I add

```
let source = (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file:///android_asset/' : '') + 'SPA/index.html/parameter=foo';
```

Edit:

I am using sources in

```
<WebView
      originWhitelist={["file://"]}
      useWebKit={true}
      onMessage={this.invoke.listener}
      source={{
        uri: source
      }}
      style={{ marginTop: 20, flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
      bounces={false}
      scrollEnabled={false}
      overScrollMode={'never'}
    />
```

Comment: first of all, try to paste your `URL` into a web page and see the result.  it seems that the page you are trying to view is not found or does not exist at all. it might be an issue with the URL link and not related to your implementation, It's okey.

Comment: @nima URL Worked on local browser it just didn't work in react native.

Comment: do you set the `source` variable in a useEffect after the component did mount? Try to add the URL inline in your `WebView` to check it.

Comment: @nima After adding the source to inline I get the same error. I think query is not readable by the source in webview for local files.